# Countable union of disjoint finite sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This statement seems probably true, and for particular examples (e.g. 'all strings of length N in a given alphabet', union over all N) it holds, but I can't find any proof that doesn't rely on the axiom of countable choice, which seems like overkill. Is there a simpler proof?

Comment: One quick caveat: the sets themselves need to be countable.

Comment: @roundsquare Last time I checked, finite sets are countable.

Comment: If all the finite sets lie in a linearly ordered set then it's probably doable without choice.

Comment: @Brian My mistake. I misread. :(